# Apply/Map function to pandas dataframe to retrieve new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

Say I have a pandas dataframe with a column 'path' specifying paths to image files.

I also have a function f, say 'get_info', which makes an api call and outputs  'a', 'b' and 'c'.

I'd now like to apply f to my dataframe and in return create new columns with the output 'a', 'b' and 'c'. I'd like to do that in junks of 10 rows, to save intermediate results (as the function makes request taking some time to complete and the dataframe has many rows).

The output I desire could be a dataframe like this:

```css
        x             a                   b                    c      
35      'path1'       [[some lists]]       [[some lists]]      [[some lists]]      
1       'path2'       NaN                  NaN                 NaN       
362     'path3'       [[some lists]]       [[some lists]]      [[some lists]]
```

First I tried the following code:

```
df['a']=np.nan
df['b']=np.nan
df['c']=np.nan

for i in range(0, len(df),10):
    try:
        df[['a','b','c']].iloc[i:(i+10)]= df['path'].iloc[i:(i+10)].apply(get_info).apply(pd.Series)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[1])
```

However, this produced a dataframe with the columns 'a', 'b', 'c' all being filled with NaNs only. However, if I only run

```
df['path'].iloc[0:(0+10)].apply(get_info).apply(pd.Series)
```

the output is as expected (a dataframe with columns 'a', 'b', 'c')

I then tried:

```
df['a']=np.nan
df['b']=np.nan
df['c']=np.nan

for i in range(0, len(df),10):
    try:
        df['a'].iloc[i:(i+10)], df['b'].iloc[i:(i+10)], df['c'].iloc[i:(i+10)]\
        = zip(*df['path'].iloc[i:(i+10)].map(get_info))
        df.to_pickle('somepath')
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[i])
```

For this code I however get the following errors

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

**EDIT**: as per @pshep123's request, here the code of the function:

```
def get_info(path): 
    data = open(path, 'rb') 

    retries =0   
    while retries < 2:
        try:        
         # Execute the REST API call and get the response.
            response = requests.request('POST', uri_base + '/detect', data=data, headers=headers, params=params)
            faces = json.loads(response.text)                    
            a=[]
            b=[]
            c=[]
            for face in faces:
                a.append(face['faceAttributes']['emotion']['anger'])
                b.append(face['faceAttributes']['emotion']['contempt'])
                c.append(face['faceAttributes']['emotion']['disgust'])               
            return a, b, c

        except: 
            if retries <2:
                time.sleep(60) 
                retries+=1
            else:
                return np.nan

    return np.nan
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Part of your problem: your `sys.exc_info()[i]` is using the `i` from the `for` loop.  You want `[1]` instead.

Comment: Also, would be really helpful if you included the `transform_x` function so we can see what the output is (or is supposed to be).

Comment: thanks for the useful comment. I also included the function (renamed to 'get_info')

Comment: @pshep123 any ideas now with the additional info?